# Node/Angular/Express routing issue

Tags: node.js, routes, express, angularjs, salesforce

I'm creating a simple node app using the node angular seed + express (https://github.com/btford/angular-express-blog/), which I'm trying to tie into Salesforce REST for data. I selected a node package that provides the auth and CRUD layer to Salesforce called NForce (https://github.com/kevinohara80/nforce).

I've created a simple authentication flow that uses a get route defined in my node app. The problem is that although the url gets loaded, and I'm assuming the routing happens, I am not being redirected as prescribed by my route get function. Oddly, if I refresh the page after clicking my Login button (which then has the auth url), all of the right events start happening and I'm redirected into an OAuth flow as expected.

The route in question is '/oauth/authenticate'

I can't tell if this is an Angular issue with the node routes, that aren't defined in Angular:
https://github.com/greenstork/donor-360/blob/master/public/js/app.js

Or if this is an issue with how I've structured the routes in Node:

https://github.com/greenstork/donor-360/blob/master/app.js

https://github.com/greenstork/donor-360/tree/master/routes

I'm relatively new to node and JS MVC programming so any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you aware that you have uploaded your Sales force API credentials to github?